# How to start EditText (Xamarin.Forms Entry) on number tab?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I'm using an Xamarin.Forms.Entry control to capture input of a barcode which almost always starts from numbers but can contain text. I want to use standard android keyboard (Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassText) but I'd like to start the keyboard on the numbers tab (see picture). Is it possible to get this behaviour?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on my test, we could not show that keyboard.

If you want to show the Numeric kayboard, you could set in xml or do the custom renderer.

xml:

```
<Entry Keyboard="Numeric"></Entry>
```

Custom renderer:

```
var native = Control as EditText;
            native.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassNumber | Android.Text.InputTypes.NumberFlagSigned | Android.Text.InputTypes.NumberFlagDecimal | InputTypes.ClassText;
```

Or create you own keyboard. It is complex. You could follow the steps in the link.
https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-create-a-custom-keyboard-with-xamarin-forms-android-4fa3b83dad1d

I do that, it works well. You could download the source file from the link below.
https://github.com/FabriBertani/CustomKeyboardXamarinForms

[image]