# Numeric keyboard as default on Xamarin.Forms, but allow text (cross platform)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Keyboard="Numeric" changes the default input keyboard to a numeric one, but it also makes it so that only numbers and decimal points are accepted -- and there is no way to switch back to an alphanumerical keyboard.

Does anybody know of a way to have the numeric keyboard appear at first, but allow the user to also input text if needed?

Edit: I need this to work for both Android and iOS

Comment: You can always have a button somewhere in the UI to toggle the input? Btw. is this Xamarin.Forms or what?

Comment: Yes, Xamarin.Forms, sorry. I'll try and see what I can do with your suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own kayboard with mumber and text like A, B, C, D.....

The link below include how to do this in custom renderer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60034046/11850033

[image]

Comment: Thanks, only 10 letters are needed in addition to numbers so it may be worth it to create a custom keyboard. I'll try this solution.

Comment: I just looked into it and it seems this would be a solution for only Android, right? Sorry, I forgot to add in my main post that I need a cross platform solution for both Android and iOS.

Comment: You could check the code sample in the link about the ios custom kayboard.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47870883/11850033