# Xamarin Forms Numeric Keyboard - enable space and dash buttons

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a requirement where a field in a Xamarin Forms app is allowed to have only numbers, spaces and dashes. Numeric keyboard layout appears to be perfect for this purpose - the only trouble - the space and dash buttons do not appear to work? Is there any way to enable these, specifically on Android - as that is the primary target platform.

Buttons in question are highlighted.

```xml
<Entry
                            x:Name="BarcodeEntry"
                            Margin="12,0"
                            HeightRequest="40"
                            Placeholder="Barcode"
                            Style="{StaticResource BorderlessEntryStyle}"
                            Keyboard="Numeric"
                            Text="{Binding Barcode.Value, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Control is bound to this property:

```cs
private string _barcode;
        public string Barcode
        {
            get => _barcode;
            set { SetProperty(ref _barcode, value); }
```

[image]

Comment: Try using Telephone, that could work

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that does work - however looks somewhat cluttered - so I was hoping to find a way to enable these buttons on Numeric Keyboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the numberic keyboard, we only have four related InputTypes.

- number: A numeric only field.
- numberDecimal: Can be combined with number and its other options to allow a decimal (fractional) number.
- numberPassword:  A numeric password field.
- numberSigned: Can be combined with number and its other options to allow a signed number.

For more details about the InputTypes, you could refer to the link below. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:inputType

If you want to use the space and dash buttons, you could use the Telephone keyboard. Or you could create your own custom keyboard.

Custom Keyboard: [Numeric keyboard as default on Xamarin.Forms, but allow text (cross platform)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68916881/numeric-keyboard-as-default-on-xamarin-forms-but-allow-text-cross-platform/68919197#68919197)

Comment: Thank you, looks like I'll have to go with TelephoneKeyboard for now, as I don't feel adventurous enough to create a custom keyboard just yet.