# Entry field in Xamarin.Forms in Hiragana/Katakana/Kanji mode

Tags: c#, xamarin, multilingual

i'm making a personal application using Xamarin Forms to register words in my own language (spanish) with the traducction in Hiragana, Katakana or Kanji.

Then i have fields (entrys) to write the text in each type but i want to write the text without needing to change my input keyboard when i'm introducing the text.

I have been searching but i only found a way using IMEMode in Windows Forms (not working in Xamaring Forms) and other replacing text directly from a character database.

Are there any library, NuGet Package, xalm attribute or something to change the character mode in entry object in Xamarin Forms to Hiragana/Katakana/Kanji?

Thanks.

Marcos.

Comment: A easy is to add a japaness keyboard. If you do not want to change your keyboard, you could create your own keyboard with Hiragana/Katakana/Kanji. But it is too complex.

Comment: Yes, but i'm trying that exactly. Write in Hiragana without install any keyboard using something like ImeMode in Windows Forms.

Comment: You could try to create a custom keyboard. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68916881/numeric-keyboard-as-default-on-xamarin-forms-but-allow-text-cross-platform/68919197#68919197